# How to use JSONDeserializer to deserialize this string?

Tags: java, json

I have string like follows:

```
    {"226167":"myshow","3193":"yourshow"}
```

How can I use JSONDeserializer to extract (226167,3193) from the above string object?

I probably want to have a list (226167,3193,...) from the above string. I am using flexjason 1.9.2 and it doesn't have jsonObject class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jackson JSON library's ObjectMapper class to deserialize into a Map and then get the keySet():

Required Import:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

Example:

```
public void readValueAsMap() throws Exception
{
    String value = "{\"226167\":\"myshow\",\"3193\":\"yourshow\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String,String> valueAsMap = mapper.readValue(value, Map.class);
    Collection<String> values = valueAsMap.keySet();
    assertTrue(values.contains("226167"));
    assertTrue(values.contains("3193"));
}
```